# Pass Backbone View inside JQuery event

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have this event on html tag out of view

```
 $(".submit-btn").click(this.saveAnswers);
```

However, I need to pass my view into the function

```
$(".submit-btn").click(this.saveAnswers, this);
```

won't work.

Is there other way to address view than `$el` and `this`?

Comment: Just wondering what is the use case for this and why wouldn't you use the backbone events to perform the click action?

Comment: Because of the complicated structure it is really hard to include submit button into the view. Maybe I can bind events on them to the view, but that was the kind of answer I was looking for.
Anyway, I guess there should be some way to pass view itself. It work for backbone events like 
this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);

Comment: I obviously don't know how the code is structured but I'd suggest if the submit button only fires off a function that lives inside a single view then it would by rights live *inside* that view. You could also do something like `var _this = this; $(".submit-btn").click(function(event){ _this.saveAnswers(event, _this); });` where you have a signature like `this.saveAnswers(event, view)` assuming `this` is a backbone view

Comment: I tried this variant without passing the event and it was no luck. But it helped with it!:)
Thank you!

Comment: and yeah, you are right, it should live inside. It just really can't in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the saveAnswers function to the view, before you call $().click. Do this:

```
var boundFunction = _.bind(this.saveAnswers, this);
$(".submit-btn").click(boundFunction);
```